# Linking a java program with MySQL using JDBC on Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, jdbc

I would like to link a Java Program on Netbeans with MySQL using JDBC drivers. I know that there are Netbeans tools to facilitate the connections, but can I do so with Java programs written in Netbeans?

I got the tutorial in here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-db-connections.htm.

```
package jdbc.connections;
import java.sql.*;  // for standard JDBC programs
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JDBCConnections 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        try 
        {
            //registering jdbc driver
            Class.forName("MySQL (Connector/J driver)");              
        }        
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ mysql";
        String USER = "username";
        String PASS = "password";
        Connection conn;

        try             
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName = Alfreds Futterkiste");
            System.out.println(rs);
        } 
        catch (SQLException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(JDBCConnections.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }           
    }    
}
```

Comment: Netbeans is just an IDE. You can connect your Java Application to a MySQL database using JDBC drivers. There are ample resources available to do that.

Comment: Add the stacktrace please if you get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I find wrong in your program

1. `Class.forName("MySQL (Connector/J driver)");` Here you are supposed to write the name of the class which is `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`
2. `String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/ mysql";` The term `mysql` written in the end is supposed to be the name of database. Make sure you have a database named as `mysql` in `MySQL Server`. And there should be no space in its name.

So it should be `String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName";`

3. `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName = Alfreds Futterkiste` It should be `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerName = 'Alfreds Futterkiste'`

Comment: wow thanks, i totally did not know abt 1. i did suspect something is wrong with 2, but i did not know what, and 3 is a careless mistake i should not have made.

Answer (score 0):

In `Class.forName` you have to add the driver's classname

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

and you must have the `mysql-connector-java-<version>-bin.jar` in your classpath.